# Mutate a Struct using closures

Tags: swift

I have a struct with a bunch of mutating funcs. The barebones of the mutating funcs have a lot of overlapping content. I would like to write a wrapper mutating func that will accept closures (which will vary). However, this results in an exclusive access error to my struct.

In an attempt to get by this, I have come up with this. As an example,

```
struct Person {
    var name: String

    mutating func modify(modifier: (inout Self) -> ()) {
        modifier(&self)
    }
}

var p = Person(name: "George")

p.modify() { inoutSelf in
    inoutSelf.name = "Frank"
}

print("\(p.name)")
```

This compiles and runs fine. But, is this safe? Thanks

#### Additional Info

To clarify, I am writing a custom walker to apple's [swift-markdown](https://github.com/apple/swift-markdown) implementation. This involves inheriting from protocol `MarkupWalker` which has a couple of mutating funcs. We descend into each child of the markup tree while walking (So, I need any changes to the state of the walker to be effective when descending into a child).

For example,

```
struct ParagraphWalker: MarkupWalker {
    var fonts: CustomFonts

    mutating func visitMarkedUpElement(_ element: Markup, preDescent: (inout Self) -> (), postDescent: (inout Self) -> ()) {
        preVisit(&self)
        descendInto(element)
        postVisit(&self)
    }


mutating func visitEmphasis(_ emphasis: Emphasis) -> () {
        visitMarkedUpElement(emphasis, preDescent: { inoutSelf in
            inoutSelf.fonts.body.addFontTrait(.italic)
        }, postDescent: { inoutSelf in
            inoutSelf.fonts.body.removeFontTrait(.italic)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What about converting it into a class?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't seem to be able to use a class. `mutating func descendInto(_ markup: Markup)` has a default implementation (which I need to use). Trying to call that from a class gives me an error `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable` at the call site of `descendInto()` in `visitMarkedUpElement()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to synchronously perform memory operations like this.

Like you noticed, Swift will [correctly enforce exclusive access to memory](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/memorysafety) to avoid memory corruption errors.
As Swift is memory-safe by default, if something compiles, it's most likely safe (with the exception of the `withUnsafe` class of functions/methods).

Your `modify` method is taking a reference to the person object and modifying the data in place in your closure.
`inout Self` is simply passed through to your custom closure, so as long as you don't reference `p` in this closure, there will be no conflicting access.

```swift
var p = Person(name: "George")

p.modify() { inoutSelf in
    inoutSelf.name = p.name // Error: conflicting access
}
```

You should be careful adding indirection like this though, as if it's not well motivated it can be very confusing to others reading your code. It's not clear what your goal is for a "wrapper mutating func", but there may be more idiomatic ways to achieve what you're trying to do using something like [`KeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath)s, which can reference fields of a data type and then allow you to read/modify data using a dynamic path.

```swift
var p = Person(name: "George")

let kp: WritableKeyPath<Person, String> = \.name
p[keyPath: kp] = "Frank"

print("\(p.name)") // "Frank"
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added some additional context on what I am trying to do. I tried to play around with WritableKeyPath, but, didn't find a way to do so. Would you have any suggestions on a more idiomatic way to approach this?

Comment: @georgemp Thanks for the additional context. Your design looks good to me as the closures are clearly named and your data manipulation is isolated to those closures! `KeyPath` wouldn't be a good fit here 